# SIM808 Doesn't detect SMS if sent while offline

Tags: arduino-uno, sim808

I'm running UNV SIM808 Shield with Arduino Uno using [DFRobot_SIM808](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_SIM808). The shield has no issues detecting incoming SMS while **powered on**. I just found out if the shield is **off** while sending the SMS, it won't detect it when it becomes online again.

```js
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 160
char message[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
int messageIndex = 0;

char phone[16];
char datetime[24];

#define PIN_TX    3
#define PIN_RX    2

SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX,PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //******** Initialize sim808 module *************
   while(!sim808.init())  { Serial.println("Starting Sim808...");   sim808.powerUpDown(9); }

  delay(3000);  
  Serial.println("Init Success, please send SMS message to me!");
}

void loop() {
  //*********** Detecting unread SMS ************************
   messageIndex = sim808.isSMSunread();
    Serial.print("messageIndex: ");
    Serial.println(messageIndex);

   //*********** At least, there is one UNREAD SMS ***********
   if (messageIndex > 0) { 
      sim808.readSMS(messageIndex, message, MESSAGE_LENGTH, phone, datetime);
                 
      //***********In order not to full SIM Memory, is better to delete it**********
      sim808.deleteSMS(messageIndex);
      Serial.print("From number: ");
      Serial.println(phone);  
      Serial.print("Datetime: ");
      Serial.println(datetime);        
      Serial.print("Recieved Message: ");
      Serial.println(message);    
   }
}
```

I'm sharing the serial monitor data after powering off the shield. I sent a this message (**2:24**) at 2:24 AM local time. **10 mins** later, I powered the shield **on** and waited for the message to be detected but with no luck for **15 mins**. I sent another message (**2:49**) local time while the shield is **on** and it was detected right away along with the previous message.

> It runs every 3 seconds but I cleaned the data

```js
02:34:56.342 -> Starting Sim808...
02:35:06.958 -> Init Success, please send SMS message to me!
02:35:09.602 -> messageIndex: -1
02:40:00.686 -> messageIndex: 0
02:45:02.311 -> messageIndex: 0
02:49:26.940 -> messageIndex: 0
02:49:29.560 -> messageIndex: 0
02:49:32.216 -> messageIndex: 0
02:49:33.565 -> messageIndex: 7
02:49:36.269 -> From number: +***********
02:49:36.322 -> Datetime: 21/04/21,02:24:20+12
02:49:36.369 -> Recieved Message: 2:24
02:49:37.624 -> messageIndex: 8
02:49:40.373 -> From number: +***********
02:49:40.373 -> Datetime: 21/04/21,02:49:28+12
02:49:40.426 -> Recieved Message: 2:49
02:49:43.029 -> messageIndex: 0
02:49:45.691 -> messageIndex: 0
02:49:48.314 -> messageIndex: 0
```

Here is code for **sim808.isSMSunread();** function. Maybe there is something can be tweaked within the code can mitigate this issue:

```js
char DFRobot_SIM808::isSMSunread(){
    char gprsBuffer[48];  //48 is enough to see +CMGL:
    char *s;
    
    sim808_check_with_cmd("AT+CMGF=1\r\n","OK\r\n",CMD);    delay(1000);
    sim808_send_cmd(F("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\",1\r\n"));
    sim808_clean_buffer(gprsBuffer,31); 
    sim808_read_buffer(gprsBuffer,30,DEFAULT_TIMEOUT); 

    if(NULL != ( s = strstr(gprsBuffer,"OK"))) {
        delay(50);
        return 0;
    } else {
        sim808_wait_for_resp("OK\r\n", CMD);        
        sim808_send_cmd("AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\",1\r\n");
        sim808_clean_buffer(gprsBuffer,48); 
        sim808_read_buffer(gprsBuffer,47,DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        if(NULL != ( s = strstr(gprsBuffer,"+CMGL:"))) {
            s = strstr(gprsBuffer,":");
            if (s != NULL) {
                sim808_wait_for_resp("OK\r\n", CMD);
                return atoi(s+1);
            }
        } else {
            return -1; 
        }
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

***What i'm looking for is to make the shield detect any unread messages if it was sent while off?***

[image]

Comment: you will have to build a time machine

Comment: sounds like your provider does not store SMS messages and transmits when your device comes online ... test it with your cell phone ... turn off your phone and send SMS to your phone .... then turn on your phone

Comment: @jsotola Once I put the sim in my phone, I got the SMS immediately.

Comment: then you need to learn how the phone retrieves stored messages ... it has nothing to do with the arduino

Comment: do the sim808 have at commands like in this page https://www.developershome.com/sms/readSmsByAtCommands.asp ?

Comment: @user30878 I'm not quiet sure if I understood you, but yes the module is responding to AT commands and this how to it works.

Comment: Check the page I'm linking to.

Comment: @user30878, as I understand it, they're having problems retrieving messages that were queued on the network after having just powered up; not problems with reading messages generally.

Comment: @timemage the command "CMGR" is said to receive SMS from storage area. I don't know what the storage is, but the comments above said it might be the solution.

Comment: this question is worth a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867646/minicom-atcmgr-n-not-showing-the-sms-content   the URL given in the answer has the details about storage https://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/receivesmsat/

Comment: @user30878 I tried all possible storage types but end up with the same issue. AT+CPMS="SM" and then ME, MT, SM_P, ME_P and MT